# how to update godaddy Dedicated linux server centos 6.9 kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, meltdown, spectre

I have dedicated server from godaddy.

The Linux information is as follows.
Version: CentOS release 6.9 (Final)
Kernel: 2.6.32-042stab111.11

I have executed "yum update" on server and now /boot shows the following files.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   108169 Nov 15 11:56 config-2.6.32-696.16.1.el6.x86_64
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   108228 Jan  4 12:36 config-2.6.32-696.18.7.el6.x86_64
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Nov 15 20:27 grub
-rw------- 1 root root 14284966 Nov 24 11:17 initramfs-2.6.32-696.16.1.el6.x86_64.img
-rw------- 1 root root 14285528 Jan 24 04:23 initramfs-2.6.32-696.18.7.el6.x86_64.img
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   215634 Nov 15 11:56 symvers-2.6.32-696.16.1.el6.x86_64.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   215711 Jan  4 12:37 symvers-2.6.32-696.18.7.el6.x86_64.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2622609 Nov 15 11:56 System.map-2.6.32-696.16.1.el6.x86_64
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2627250 Jan  4 12:36 System.map-2.6.32-696.18.7.el6.x86_64
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4276336 Nov 15 11:56 vmlinuz-2.6.32-696.16.1.el6.x86_64
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4282992 Jan  4 12:36 vmlinuz-2.6.32-696.18.7.el6.x86_64
```

installed rpm shows the following packages:

```
kernel-firmware-2.6.32-696.18.7.el6.noarch
dracut-kernel-004-409.el6_8.2.noarch
kernel-headers-2.6.32-696.18.7.el6.x86_64
kernel-devel-2.6.32-696.18.7.el6.x86_64
kernel-devel-2.6.32-696.16.1.el6.x86_64
kernel-2.6.32-696.16.1.el6.x86_64
kernel-2.6.32-696.18.7.el6.x86_64
```

and rebooted the server.

But,The kernel is still the old version only.

uname output before update and boot:

```
Linux x.x.x.secureserver.net 2.6.32-042stab111.11 #1 SMP Tue Sep 1 18:19:12 MSK 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Update log:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Update Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/metalink                                                                                          |  13 kB     00:00
 * base: mirrors.usc.edu
 * epel: linux.mirrors.es.net
 * extras: centos-distro.cavecreek.net
 * updates: mirror.san.fastserv.com
base                                                                                                   | 3.7 kB     00:00
elastic-5.x                                                                                            | 1.3 kB     00:00
elastic-5.x/primary                                                                                    | 121 kB     00:00
elastic-5.x                                                                                                           314/314
epel                                                                                                   | 4.7 kB     00:00
epel/primary_db                                                                                        | 6.0 MB     00:00
extras                                                                                                 | 3.4 kB     00:00
mysql56-community                                                                                      | 2.5 kB     00:00
nodesource                                                                                             | 2.5 kB     00:00
updates                                                                                                | 3.4 kB     00:00
updates/primary_db                                                                                     | 5.8 MB     00:02
wazuh_repo                                                                                             | 3.3 kB     00:00
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package apr.x86_64 0:1.3.9-5.el6_2 will be updated
---> Package apr.x86_64 0:1.3.9-5.el6_9.1 will be an update
---> Package bind.x86_64 32:9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.4 will be updated
---> Package bind.x86_64 32:9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.5 will be an update
---> Package bind-libs.x86_64 32:9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.4 will be updated
---> Package bind-libs.x86_64 32:9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.5 will be an update
---> Package elasticsearch.noarch 0:5.6.4-1 will be updated
---> Package elasticsearch.noarch 0:5.6.6-1 will be an update
---> Package filebeat.x86_64 0:5.6.4-1 will be updated
---> Package filebeat.x86_64 0:5.6.6-1 will be an update
---> Package kernel.x86_64 0:2.6.32-696.18.7.el6 will be installed
---> Package kernel-devel.x86_64 0:2.6.32-696.18.7.el6 will be installed
---> Package kernel-firmware.noarch 0:2.6.32-696.16.1.el6 will be updated
---> Package kernel-firmware.noarch 0:2.6.32-696.18.7.el6 will be an update
---> Package kernel-headers.x86_64 0:2.6.32-696.16.1.el6 will be updated
---> Package kernel-headers.x86_64 0:2.6.32-696.18.7.el6 will be an update
---> Package kibana.x86_64 0:5.6.4-1 will be updated
---> Package kibana.x86_64 0:5.6.6-1 will be an update
---> Package logstash.noarch 1:5.6.4-1 will be updated
---> Package logstash.noarch 1:5.6.6-1 will be an update
---> Package mysql-community-client.x86_64 0:5.6.38-2.el6 will be updated
---> Package mysql-community-client.x86_64 0:5.6.39-2.el6 will be an update
---> Package mysql-community-common.x86_64 0:5.6.38-2.el6 will be updated
---> Package mysql-community-common.x86_64 0:5.6.39-2.el6 will be an update
---> Package mysql-community-libs.x86_64 0:5.6.38-2.el6 will be updated
---> Package mysql-community-libs.x86_64 0:5.6.39-2.el6 will be an update
---> Package mysql-community-libs-compat.x86_64 0:5.6.38-2.el6 will be updated
---> Package mysql-community-libs-compat.x86_64 0:5.6.39-2.el6 will be an update
---> Package mysql-community-server.x86_64 0:5.6.38-2.el6 will be updated
---> Package mysql-community-server.x86_64 0:5.6.39-2.el6 will be an update
---> Package nodejs.x86_64 2:6.12.0-1nodesource will be updated
---> Package nodejs.x86_64 2:6.12.3-1nodesource will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

==============================================================================================================================
 Package                               Arch             Version                             Repository                   Size
==============================================================================================================================
Installing:
 kernel                                x86_64           2.6.32-696.18.7.el6                 updates                      32 M
 kernel-devel                          x86_64           2.6.32-696.18.7.el6                 updates                      11 M
Updating:
 apr                                   x86_64           1.3.9-5.el6_9.1                     updates                     124 k
 bind                                  x86_64           32:9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.5           updates                     4.0 M
 bind-libs                             x86_64           32:9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.5           updates                     892 k
 elasticsearch                         noarch           5.6.6-1                             elastic-5.x                  32 M
 filebeat                              x86_64           5.6.6-1                             elastic-5.x                 8.8 M
 kernel-firmware                       noarch           2.6.32-696.18.7.el6                 updates                      29 M
 kernel-headers                        x86_64           2.6.32-696.18.7.el6                 updates                     4.5 M
 kibana                                x86_64           5.6.6-1                             elastic-5.x                  51 M
 logstash                              noarch           1:5.6.6-1                           elastic-5.x                  99 M
 mysql-community-client                x86_64           5.6.39-2.el6                        mysql56-community            18 M
 mysql-community-common                x86_64           5.6.39-2.el6                        mysql56-community           308 k
 mysql-community-libs                  x86_64           5.6.39-2.el6                        mysql56-community           1.9 M
 mysql-community-libs-compat           x86_64           5.6.39-2.el6                        mysql56-community           1.6 M
 mysql-community-server                x86_64           5.6.39-2.el6                        mysql56-community            55 M
 nodejs                                x86_64           2:6.12.3-1nodesource                nodesource                   13 M

Transaction Summary
==============================================================================================================================
Install       2 Package(s)
Upgrade      15 Package(s)

Total download size: 361 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
(1/17): apr-1.3.9-5.el6_9.1.x86_64.rpm                                                                 | 124 kB     00:00
(2/17): bind-9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.5.x86_64.rpm                                                         | 4.0 MB     00:00
(3/17): bind-libs-9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.5.x86_64.rpm                                                    | 892 kB     00:00
(4/17): elasticsearch-5.6.6.rpm                                                                        |  32 MB     00:02
(5/17): filebeat-5.6.6-x86_64.rpm                                                                      | 8.8 MB     00:00
(6/17): kernel-2.6.32-696.18.7.el6.x86_64.rpm                                                          |  32 MB     00:02
(7/17): kernel-devel-2.6.32-696.18.7.el6.x86_64.rpm                                                    |  11 MB     00:01
(8/17): kernel-firmware-2.6.32-696.18.7.el6.noarch.rpm                                                 |  29 MB     00:03
(9/17): kernel-headers-2.6.32-696.18.7.el6.x86_64.rpm                                                  | 4.5 MB     00:00
(10/17): kibana-5.6.6-x86_64.rpm                                                                       |  51 MB     00:02
(11/17): logstash-5.6.6.rpm                                                                            |  99 MB     00:04
(12/17): mysql-community-client-5.6.39-2.el6.x86_64.rpm                                                |  18 MB     00:01
(13/17): mysql-community-common-5.6.39-2.el6.x86_64.rpm                                                | 308 kB     00:00
(14/17): mysql-community-libs-5.6.39-2.el6.x86_64.rpm                                                  | 1.9 MB     00:00
(15/17): mysql-community-libs-compat-5.6.39-2.el6.x86_64.rpm                                           | 1.6 MB     00:00
(16/17): mysql-community-server-5.6.39-2.el6.x86_64.rpm                                                |  55 MB     00:03
(17/17): nodejs-6.12.3-1nodesource.x86_64.rpm                                                          |  13 MB     00:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                                          15 MB/s | 361 MB     00:24
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
  Updating   : mysql-community-common-5.6.39-2.el6.x86_64                                                                1/32
  Updating   : mysql-community-libs-5.6.39-2.el6.x86_64                                                                  2/32
  Updating   : mysql-community-client-5.6.39-2.el6.x86_64                                                                3/32
  Updating   : kernel-firmware-2.6.32-696.18.7.el6.noarch                                                                4/32
  Updating   : 32:bind-libs-9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.5.x86_64                                                                5/32
  Updating   : 32:bind-9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.5.x86_64                                                                     6/32
  Installing : kernel-2.6.32-696.18.7.el6.x86_64                                                                         7/32
  Updating   : mysql-community-server-5.6.39-2.el6.x86_64                                                                8/32
  Updating   : mysql-community-libs-compat-5.6.39-2.el6.x86_64                                                           9/32
  Installing : kernel-devel-2.6.32-696.18.7.el6.x86_64                                                                  10/32
  Updating   : filebeat-5.6.6-1.x86_64                                                                                  11/32
  Updating   : 1:logstash-5.6.6-1.noarch                                                                                12/32
Using provided startup.options file: /etc/logstash/startup.options
Successfully created system startup script for Logstash
  Updating   : kernel-headers-2.6.32-696.18.7.el6.x86_64                                                                13/32
  Updating   : kibana-5.6.6-1.x86_64                                                                                    14/32
Detected old npm client, removing...
  Updating   : 2:nodejs-6.12.3-1nodesource.x86_64                                                                       15/32
  Updating   : apr-1.3.9-5.el6_9.1.x86_64                                                                               16/32
  Updating   : elasticsearch-5.6.6-1.noarch                                                                             17/32
warning: /etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch created as /etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch.rpmnew
  Cleanup    : kernel-firmware-2.6.32-696.16.1.el6.noarch                                                               18/32
  Cleanup    : filebeat-5.6.4-1.x86_64                                                                                  19/32
  Cleanup    : 1:logstash-5.6.4-1.noarch                                                                                20/32
  Cleanup    : kernel-headers-2.6.32-696.16.1.el6.x86_64                                                                21/32
Stopping kibana service... OK
  Cleanup    : kibana-5.6.4-1.x86_64                                                                                    22/32
  Cleanup    : elasticsearch-5.6.4-1.noarch                                                                             23/32
  Cleanup    : mysql-community-server-5.6.38-2.el6.x86_64                                                               24/32
  Cleanup    : mysql-community-client-5.6.38-2.el6.x86_64                                                               25/32
  Cleanup    : mysql-community-libs-compat-5.6.38-2.el6.x86_64                                                          26/32
  Cleanup    : mysql-community-libs-5.6.38-2.el6.x86_64                                                                 27/32
  Cleanup    : 32:bind-9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.4.x86_64                                                                    28/32
  Cleanup    : mysql-community-common-5.6.38-2.el6.x86_64                                                               29/32
  Cleanup    : 32:bind-libs-9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.4.x86_64                                                               30/32
  Cleanup    : 2:nodejs-6.12.0-1nodesource.x86_64                                                                       31/32
  Cleanup    : apr-1.3.9-5.el6_2.x86_64                                                                                 32/32
  Verifying  : elasticsearch-5.6.6-1.noarch                                                                              1/32
  Verifying  : 32:bind-9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.5.x86_64                                                                     2/32
  Verifying  : mysql-community-client-5.6.39-2.el6.x86_64                                                                3/32
  Verifying  : apr-1.3.9-5.el6_9.1.x86_64                                                                                4/32
  Verifying  : 2:nodejs-6.12.3-1nodesource.x86_64                                                                        5/32
  Verifying  : kibana-5.6.6-1.x86_64                                                                                     6/32
  Verifying  : 32:bind-libs-9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.5.x86_64                                                                7/32
  Verifying  : mysql-community-libs-5.6.39-2.el6.x86_64                                                                  8/32
  Verifying  : mysql-community-server-5.6.39-2.el6.x86_64                                                                9/32
  Verifying  : kernel-headers-2.6.32-696.18.7.el6.x86_64                                                                10/32
  Verifying  : 1:logstash-5.6.6-1.noarch                                                                                11/32
  Verifying  : filebeat-5.6.6-1.x86_64                                                                                  12/32
  Verifying  : mysql-community-libs-compat-5.6.39-2.el6.x86_64                                                          13/32
  Verifying  : mysql-community-common-5.6.39-2.el6.x86_64                                                               14/32
  Verifying  : kernel-2.6.32-696.18.7.el6.x86_64                                                                        15/32
  Verifying  : kernel-firmware-2.6.32-696.18.7.el6.noarch                                                               16/32
  Verifying  : kernel-devel-2.6.32-696.18.7.el6.x86_64                                                                  17/32
  Verifying  : 2:nodejs-6.12.0-1nodesource.x86_64                                                                       18/32
  Verifying  : kibana-5.6.4-1.x86_64                                                                                    19/32
  Verifying  : kernel-headers-2.6.32-696.16.1.el6.x86_64                                                                20/32
  Verifying  : mysql-community-libs-5.6.38-2.el6.x86_64                                                                 21/32
  Verifying  : kernel-firmware-2.6.32-696.16.1.el6.noarch                                                               22/32
  Verifying  : mysql-community-server-5.6.38-2.el6.x86_64                                                               23/32
  Verifying  : 32:bind-9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.4.x86_64                                                                    24/32
  Verifying  : filebeat-5.6.4-1.x86_64                                                                                  25/32
  Verifying  : elasticsearch-5.6.4-1.noarch                                                                             26/32
  Verifying  : mysql-community-libs-compat-5.6.38-2.el6.x86_64                                                          27/32
  Verifying  : apr-1.3.9-5.el6_2.x86_64                                                                                 28/32
  Verifying  : 1:logstash-5.6.4-1.noarch                                                                                29/32
  Verifying  : mysql-community-common-5.6.38-2.el6.x86_64                                                               30/32
  Verifying  : 32:bind-libs-9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.4.x86_64                                                               31/32
  Verifying  : mysql-community-client-5.6.38-2.el6.x86_64                                                               32/32

Installed:
  kernel.x86_64 0:2.6.32-696.18.7.el6                        kernel-devel.x86_64 0:2.6.32-696.18.7.el6

Updated:
  apr.x86_64 0:1.3.9-5.el6_9.1                                     bind.x86_64 32:9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.5
  bind-libs.x86_64 32:9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.5                       elasticsearch.noarch 0:5.6.6-1
  filebeat.x86_64 0:5.6.6-1                                        kernel-firmware.noarch 0:2.6.32-696.18.7.el6
  kernel-headers.x86_64 0:2.6.32-696.18.7.el6                      kibana.x86_64 0:5.6.6-1
  logstash.noarch 1:5.6.6-1                                        mysql-community-client.x86_64 0:5.6.39-2.el6
  mysql-community-common.x86_64 0:5.6.39-2.el6                     mysql-community-libs.x86_64 0:5.6.39-2.el6
  mysql-community-libs-compat.x86_64 0:5.6.39-2.el6                mysql-community-server.x86_64 0:5.6.39-2.el6
  nodejs.x86_64 2:6.12.3-1nodesource

Complete!
```

Uname after reboot:

```
Linux x.x.x..secureserver.net 2.6.32-042stab111.11 #1 SMP Tue Sep 1 18:19:12 MSK 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I thought something was wrong and tried to check the grub information but the grub.conf file does not exist on the server.

I would like to ask two questions.

How do I boot to a new kernel?
how to use grub.conf from the godaddy Dedicated server?

If someone knows this workaround, please advise me.

Thank you.

Comment: You'd think that update-grub would have been run automatically.  What happens if you run it?

Comment: And what if grub fails to boot with the new kernel, won't it fall back on the old one?

Comment: update-grub or grub2-mkconfig commands are not available on my VPC.

Comment: You are on CentOS 6, you wouldn't have grub2-mkconfig, and update-grub seems to be an Ubuntu thing.   Can you check if the new kernel has been added to /etc/grub.conf and then you may need to run grub-install.

Comment: /etc/grub.conf does not exist...grub_install does not exist...its a Dedicate Server provided by GoDaddy...it is customized.So don't treat it as common Linux Server...

Comment: Perhaps GoDaddy has a special procedure to update your system?

Comment: Have you tried to install grub itself?